# php artisan serve making my cmd prompt stuck

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 5 on windows cmd prompt.

I have very simple issue
`php artisan serve`

to start the server , My command prompt is stuck and I am not able to execute any other artisan command until I close the command line and then restart it and then execute the code and then start the laravel server.

Is there any easy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a second `cmd` prompt.

Or use a terminal emulator which supports multiple tabs. I don't know if Windows `cmd` supports the *send to background execution* command, like the `&` of the Unix `sh`.

If it is available, you should be able to run the `serve` in background and have your prompt ready for other commands. Under `sh` I would do

```
$ php artisan serve &
```

but I usually don't send to background so that I can kill it easily.

I would definitely go for two terminals.

Comment: found a way out , Have to press ctrl+c

Comment: With `Ctrl-C`, you kill the web server. If you want to run `artisan` commands while `php artisan serve` is still running, you have to keep it opened in another command prompt, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+C It will kill this and start a new command line